# Not able to install xcode_3.2.3_and_ios_sdk_4.0.2.dmg

Tags: macos, download, xcode, sdk

I have downloaded xcode_3.2.3_and_ios_sdk_4.0.2.dmg from apple website, after the download completed. I tried to install SDK, But when i double clicked on it i got small pop up stating "Warning" The Following disk images couldn't be opened the reason displayed over there is "Not Recognized". Can any one help me out.

Thank You

Comment: I just realized you've asked a similar question before. If this is happening repeatedly it may be more than just a corrupt download.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The download may be corrupt - it's happened to me multiple times. Redownload it first and then tell us what happens!

EDIT: I just realized you've asked a similar question before. If this is happening repeatedly it may be more than just a corrupt download. We can't know for sure until you try again.

Comment: also note that the file may be incompletely downloaded, which happens often in Chrome if the process is paused/interrupted.